# How do I cancel a running task by pressing Enter key in console?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose an application has a method name PrintAsterisk() that prints asterisks on a screen continuously.
The method runs on a Task separate from the user interface.
I need to ensure that the application stop printing the asterisk on screen when the user presses the Enter key.

How do I cancel a running task by pressing Enter key in console?

Below is the my method that is simplified:

```
static void PrintAsterisk() {
    while (true) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Write("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass a CancellationToken to the task and watch out for cancellation inside.

Comment: Toureg, note that you've use term "task" (which in C#/.Net posts usually refers to types in `System.Threading.Tasks`) but based on code in the post is about lower level Thread type - make sure to clarify... Also "runs on a Task that is separated from the user interface" is very confusing - not even sure what you mean there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you create a thread, you can pass `CancellationToken` to it. Inside method ran in the thread just check if that token has cancellation request an break your method if so.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thx for quick response.